# Convert Hexadecimal encoded utf8 to string inside Innoscript

Tags: unicode, inno-setup, pascal

I have some Unicode strings represented in Hexadecimal form and written in an ini file like the following:
Text to Convert=#$a5e#$a5a#$a5b

I would like to convert it to a wide-string in the Unicode version of innosetup.

I couldn't Find a way to do so.

Comment: You can build string using Pos(), Chr() and friends, but I'm not sure if they support wide characters though.

Comment: @Deanna Chr() does not support Unicode which makes this question difficult to answer.

Comment: What's the encoding of the source string?

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup allows you to call functions from third party DLLs so you can make a simple DLL that implements this function using your favorite language, and call it from Inno Setup.